# Scala NetLogo Extension API: access globals / model parameters

Tags: scala, api, netlogo

I am building a Scala extension for one of my models. I would like to utilize Scala as much as possible. I have been reading the [API reference](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/scaladoc/org/nlogo/index.html).

I am wondering if it is possible to access global variables using the Extension API. Has someone achieved this?

I have been able to set breed, turtle variables, however, I'm starting to think that (by design) an extension cannot access global variables since this inherently highly-couples the extension with the model.

If it is the case that it is possible, please provide the class in which globals can be referenced by name.

If it is not possible, is there a workaround? I could create another breed which contains all globals or passing the globals as parameters, however, those solutions are last resorts.

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer, but the short explanation is that the "observer" agent owns the global variables.  From the [world](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.0.2/docs/scaladoc/org/nlogo/api/World.html) you should be able to call `observerOwnsIndexOf()`  to get the index of the global variable using [`world.observer.getVariable()`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/6.0.2/docs/scaladoc/org/nlogo/api/Observer.html).  You can set global variables directly from the world using `setObserverVariableByName()` from the world.

Comment: I will look into this. How would you get the index of a specific parameter or global? the Observer.variables func returns an array not a dictionary of variables.

Comment: `observerOwnsIndexOf()` will give you the index from the name string, which you can use with the array or with `getVariable()`

Comment: Makes sense. Where is `observerOwnsIndexOf()` declared?

Comment: It's on the world, I believe (just going by docs at the moment, not testing code).

Comment: This worked. If you write it up as an answer ill accept it and get you some more rep. Your help is appreciated, Jasper!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetLogo tries to treat everything as an agent, and so for the global variables, those are simply `breeds-own` variables for the `observer` agent.

They can be accessed using the Extensions API from the `observer` property of the `world`.  This is probably most easily done from [the `org.nlogo.agent.World`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/scaladoc/org/nlogo/agent/World.html).  You can see [the `observer`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/scaladoc/org/nlogo/agent/Observer.html) property there, as well as a few convenience methods for interacting the "observer-owns" variables.

Here is a longer example of getting and setting globals as an extension:

```
// will return a list of lists with global names and values
object GetGlobals extends api.Reporter {

  override def getSyntax = reporterSyntax(ret = ListType)

  def report(args: Array[api.Argument], context: api.Context): AnyRef = {
    import org.nlogo.agent.World
    import org.nlogo.api.ScalaConversions.toLogoList

    val world   = context.world.asInstanceOf[World]
    val globals = world.observer.variables

    val results = (0 until globals.length).map( (i) => {
      val globalName  = world.observerOwnsNameAt(i)
      val globalValue = world.observer.getVariable(i)
      Seq( globalName, globalValue ).toLogoList
    })

    results.toLogoList
  }
}

// expects a list of lists with global names and values to set
object SetGlobals extends api.Command {

  override def getSyntax = commandSyntax(right = List(ListType))

  def perform(args: Array[api.Argument], context: api.Context) {
    import org.nlogo.agent.World
    import org.nlogo.core.LogoList

    val world      = context.world.asInstanceOf[World]
    val newGlobals = args(0).getList

    newGlobals.foreach( (newGlobalAny) => {
      val newGlobal  = newGlobalAny.asInstanceOf[LogoList]
      val globalName = newGlobal(0).asInstanceOf[String]
      val newValue   = newGlobal(1)

      world.setObserverVariableByName( globalName, newValue )
    })
  }
}
```

If you add these to an extension as `get-globals` and `set-globals` to an extension called `sample-scala`, you can use them like this:

```
extensions [ sample-scala ]

globals [ g1 g2 g3 ]

to test
  show sample-scala:get-globals
  sample-scala:set-globals [ [ "g1" 10 ] [ "g2" "hello" ] [ "g3" nobody ] ]
  show sample-scala:get-globals
end
```

And you'll see this output:

```
observer> test
observer: [["G1" 0] ["G2" 0] ["G3" 0]]
observer: [["G1" 10] ["G2" "hello"] ["G3" nobody]]
```